# how to pass the edited value to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i am making the html table with an inline edit using http://www.iwebux.com/inline-edit-using-ajax-in-jquery/ i try to pass the edited value to database but its not passing,i want to pass the id and the edited value  to database below is my code.Please anyone guide me i am new to programming thanks.

**ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function () {



  $('td.edit').click(function () {


      $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
      $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');

      $(this).addClass('ajax');
      $(this).html('<input id="editbox" size="' + $(this).text().length + '" type="text" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');

      $('#editbox').focus();
    }


  );

  $('td.edit').keydown(function (event) {


      arr = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");


      if (event.which == 13) {

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "config.php",
          data: "value=" + $('.ajax input').val() + "&rowid=" + arr[1] + "&region=" + arr[2],
          success: function (data) {
            $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
            $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
          }
        });
      }

    }




  );


  $('#editbox').live('blur', function () {

    $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
    $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
  });



});
```

**Html**

```
<body>

<table cellpadding="15"> 


<tr class="heading" bgcolor="#ccc">
    <th>region</th>
    <th>country</th>
    <th style="width:285px;">networkname</th>
         <th>mcc</th>
         <th>mnc</th>
         <th>mnp</th>
</tr>

<?php
$dbHost = 'localhost'; // usually localhost
$dbUsername = 'fms';
$dbPassword = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$dbDatabase = 'fms';
$db = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword) or die ("Unable to connect to Database Server.");
mysql_select_db ($dbDatabase, $db) or die ("Could not select database.");



$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM supplierprice");


while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
echo '<tr '.$row['id'].' >';
echo "<td class='edit' >" . $row['region'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='edit' >" . $row['country'] . "</td>";
echo "<td  class='edit' >" . $row['networkname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='edit' >" . $row['mcc'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='edit' >" . $row['mnc'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='edit'>" . $row['mnp'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

?>

</table>



</body>
```

**config.php**

```
<?php
$dbHost = 'localhost'; // usually localhost
$dbUsername = 'fms';
$dbPassword = 'xxxxxxxx';
$dbDatabase = 'fms';
$db = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword) or die ("Unable to connect to Database Server.");
mysql_select_db ($dbDatabase, $db) or die ("Could not select database.");

print $_POST['rowid'];
if($_POST['rowid'])
{
$id=mysql_escape_String($_POST['id']);
$region=mysql_escape_String($_POST['region']);
$country=mysql_escape_String($_POST['country']);
$networkname=mysql_escape_String($_POST['networkname']);
$mcc=mysql_escape_String($_POST['mcc']);
$mnc=mysql_escape_String($_POST['mnc']);
$mnp=mysql_escape_String($_POST['mnp']);
$sql = "update supplierprice set region='$region',country='$country',networkname='$networkname',mcc='$mcc',mnc='$mnc',mnp='$mnp' where id='$id'";
mysql_query($sql);
print " $sql";
}
?>
```

Comment: Try alerting in your javascript to see if you get the right values on keydown, if the javascript works, try sending an email to check if you ever enter your ajax page.. If these both work, start trying to mail some data from your ajax page to yourself. Like the $sql (could be wrong sql) or data that you get. (also try to use PDO or mysqli)

Comment: it not getting the value when print it shows region undefined
rowid ajax
value cv Ak in rowid how its get ajax and it not passing the updated value

Comment: What do you get when alert(arr) in your javascript?

Comment: its showing ajax can you go through the code please